# NPM Registry API - Scoped Packages

Tags: node.js, npm, scope, package

I am looking for scoped packages (you know, the "@scope/package-name" type of packages).

Is there a way in which I can list all scoped packages which exists under the main NPM registry (https://registry.npmjs.org)?

Good enough results will be fetching the latest scoped packages.
When I use https://registry.npmjs.org/-/all/static/month.json for fetching all of last month new packages - it does not include any scoped package. (I know that it will be deprecated on Sep 1th 2017).

If there is no such way, a sufficient solution will be to fetch all packages under a specific scope.
e.g - Getting all @angular packages (@angular/core, @angular/router, etc..).

Examples:

> https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2Fcore
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@asafsavich%2Fscope
>   https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular%2Fcommon

Thanks!

Comment: i think thats what you are looking for : https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scope

Comment: This is not what I am looking for. Please read the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Npm registry added scope support in search at Apr 2017. [REF](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/159539048360/scope-support-in-search-and-download-stats)

https://registry.npmjs.com/-/v1/search?text=scope:angular returns a package list in *@angular* scope.

Answer (score 3):

You can query the package meta info at https://registry.npmjs.com/%40scope%2Fpackage however the /latest route does not work.